# In Ruby how do I sort a hash by its key values in alphabetical order?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a hash,
{"c": 1, "b": 2, "a": 3}
How do I sort the hash so the elements are in order of the key value?

Answer (score 1):

myh = {"c" => 1, "b" => 2, "a" => 3}

myh.sort

=> [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1]]

Comment: `myh.sort.to_h` will bring it back to a hash

Answer (score 1):

```
{"c" => 1, "b" => 2, "a" => 3}.sort.to_h
```